# Insert a string in a fixed position in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, insert

I need to insert 4 strings in a text file in a fixed position:

- first string: the product, at the beginning of the line, column 1
- second one: %%b, column 20
- third one: %%c, column 33
- fourth one: doesn't exist, column 42.

I always want the strings written at the exact same position no matter how longer are the other strings before. so it should looks like the example below:

```
the product   ergerzgtrg                  65ggrth784rjhnjgbkljn   doesn't exist  
the product   reggbrtbhtrergzthrjhlyoiul  rtjntjrez               doesn't exist
the product   zef                         rt                      doesn't exist
```

Here's my code:

```
FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1-7*" %%a in (mytextfile.txt) do (
    if "%%e"=="Unkown" (
        echo the product         %%b          %%c          doesn't exist>>Unkown_product.txt
    )
)
```

mytextfile.txt looks like this:

```
K5134908-Blabla_4;K5134908;Blabla_4;01-69423;Unkown;K5134908-Blabla_4-516245;K5134908-Blabla_4-516245;
K2602207-Blabla_2;K2602207;Blabla_2;01-81111;Unkown;K2602207-Blabla_2-516245;K2602207-Blabla_2-516245;
K2602006-Blabla_3;K2602006;Blabla_3;01-82789;Unkown;K2602006-Blabla_3-516245;K2602006-Blabla_3-516245;
K2601507-Blabla_4;K2601507;Blabla_4;01-75135;Unkown;K2601507-Blabla_4-516245;K2601507-Blabla_4-516245;
```

Is there any way to do that within a batch file (.bat)?

Comment: Your example input and output files together with your provided a script do not match the task you need help with. Can you please revisit you question and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50799151/edit) it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add enough spaces to the values (20 in my example), then cut the first [whatever you need] characters (15 in my example):

```
@echo off
setlocal

FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1-7*" %%a in (mytextfile.txt) do (
    if "%%e"=="Unkown" call :format "%%b" "%%c"
)
goto :eof

:format
set "b=%~1                    "
set "c=%~2                    "
set "b=%b:~0,15%"
set "c=%c:~0,15%"
echo the product %b% %c% doesn't exist>>Unkown_product.txt
```

Note: the search string is `"Unkown"` according to your file example (probably a typo, I guess it should be `"Unknown"`)

Comment: It works perfectly well, that's what I was looking for.yes "unkown" was a typo